# Don't know why this power series representation is wrong...

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I've run into something confusing.

The problem is that I have to find the power series representation of $g(x)$ using the given $f(x)$, specifically $g(x) = \ln(1 - 3x)$ using $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$.

Now, I did it, but my result is incorrect:
$$\ln(1-3x) = \int \frac{dx}{1-3x} = \int \sum 3^{k}x^{k} = \sum \frac{3^{k}x^{k+1}}{k+1}$$

The answer at the back of my textbook is:
$$\sum \frac{3^k x^k}{k}$$

My result for the interval of convergence was however correct, which leads me to believe that there is maybe a mistake in the book's answer?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're simply neglecting the chain rule:
$$
\int\frac{dx}{1-3x} = \frac {-1} 3 \ln(1-3x) + C.
$$

Comment: Sorry to keep going with this, but the $-\frac{1}{3}$, though I understand where it came from, is yielding a completely different answer. I've been studying for 5 straight hours now so I could be doing it completely wrong, but this is what I've got:

$$-\frac{1}{3} \int \sum 3^{k}x^{k}$$

Which leads to...

$$-\frac{1}{3} \sum \frac{3^{k}x^{k+1}}{k+1}$$

Comment: you have to move the constant to the other side so it'll look like this:

$$ \ln(1-3x) = -3 \int \frac{dx}{1-3x} = -3 \int \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 3^k x^k \right)\, dx = - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^{k+1} x^{k+1}}{k+1} $$

To arrive at the answer in the book, just shift the index

$$ - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^{k+1} x^{k+1}}{k+1} = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^k x^k}{k} $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\ln(1-3x) = -3\int \dfrac{dx}{1-3x}$$ and then shift the index of summation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the chain rule: $$\ln(1-3x)=\int\dfrac{dx}{1-3x}$$
Let $u=1-3x,du=-3dx$, thus giving
$$\ln(1-3x)=\dfrac{-1}{3}\int\dfrac{du}{u}=\dfrac{-1}{3}\ln|1-3x|+C$$
Thus,
$$\ln(1-3x)=\int\dfrac{dx}{1-3x}=\sum\dfrac{3^kx^k}{k}$$